# sfdx force:cmdt:record:insert is creating record with undefined value for blank values

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I have csv file with few columns as blank value. When I create custom metadata using sfdx force:cmdt:record:insert command, it is creating those record with undefined value.

Find sample created custom metadata below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CustomMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<label>test 2</label>
<protected>false</protected>
<values>
    <field>undefined</field>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">undefined</value>
</values>
 </CustomMetadata>
```

Comment: This is something that should be reported to the sfdx cli team.